# Getting error while Deploying mBeam Microservices to mCM Container

Tags: javascript, microservices, edgeengine, edgesdk

I am working on the the **Smart-car-use-case** provided in the mimik website. When i try to follow the steps '***[B5-1] ,[B6-1], [B7-1]*** ', which will deploy the microservices to the **mCM container**, [image]

I am getting the following error in postman.

```
[json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 2: syntax error while parsing value - invalid number; expected digit after '-'; last read: '--'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the deployment of all microservices are successful. You can verify deployment by running GET http://{{YOUR_IP_ADDRESS}}:{{PORT}}/mcm/v1/images (or [B4-1] in Postman collection) and looking at the response. Your response should contain the names of all the required microservices (miot-v1, msuperdrive-v1 and mbeam-v1). If the microservices are missing; you will need to deploy them again.

NOTE:
edgeengine must be running at all times in order to complete everything correctly